# changing values directly on the destination system instead of copying file from the source

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

using ansible looking for some idea for changing values directly on the destination system instead of copying files from source.

example:

I have many files in tmpl format on the destination system and would like to change the values related to this `<%= applicationname_zk_quorum %>` by using ansible variable's dynamically.

```
/applactionname/conf/zk.properties.tmpl

[root@applicationname-7 ~]# cat /applicationname/conf/zk.properties.tmpl
#nodes in quorum

applicationname.zk.quorum=<%= applicationname_zk_quorum %>
#applicationname.zk.quorum=zook1:6666,zook2:6666,zook3:6666

applicationname.zk.node=/applicationnames/node/

#Session timeout in milliseconds
applicationname.zk.sessionTimeout=72000
```

I understand that ansible variables only support for handling yaml and don't have any idea if anything it is possible to apply something for tmpl file.

thanks a lot for all your support and guidance!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through [jinja2 documents](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs) and [Ansible template module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html)

Suppose you have this file `conf/zk.properties.tmpl.j2` in your current ansible module's `templates` folder

```
- template:
    src: conf/zk.properties.tmpl.j2
    dest: /applicationname/conf/zk.properties.tmpl
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
```

You can define the variable in `conf/zk.properties.tmpl.j2`. For example:

```
#nodes in quorum

applicationname.zk.quorum=<%= {{ applicationname_zk_quorum }} %>

applicationname.zk.node=/applicationnames/node/

#Session timeout in milliseconds
applicationname.zk.sessionTimeout=72000
```

In vars folder, you can define this variable `applicationname_zk_quorum` as a yml file, for example, `tmpl.yml`.

```
applicationname.zk.quorum: "zook1:6666,zook2:6666,zook3:6666"
```

Comment: BMW@ Thank you very much, it helped me to understand better for solving my problem with your example.

Comment: Thanks in Stackoverflow, you need to vote up the answer if it is helpful, and accept it as an answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't thought of this and update accordingly. Thanks